# Heavy computation in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and hence, I would have a few questions to ask.

I am following the tutorial based on this.

http://hplgit.github.io/web4sciapps/doc/pub/._web4sa_django006.html

They do have a compute class and it is called in the views.py to perform the computation.

compute class

```
from numpy import exp, cos, linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, time, glob

def damped_vibrations(t, A, b, w):
    return A*exp(-b*t)*cos(w*t)

def compute(A, b, w, T, resolution=500):
    """Return filename of plot of the damped_vibration function."""
    print os.getcwd()
    t = linspace(0, T, resolution+1)
    y = damped_vibrations(t, A, b, w)
    plt.figure()  # needed to avoid adding curves in plot
    plt.plot(t, y)
    plt.title('A=%g, b=%g, w=%g' % (A, b, w))
    if not os.path.isdir('static'):
        os.mkdir('static')
    else:
        # Remove old plot files
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join('static', '*.png')):
            os.remove(filename)
    # Use time since Jan 1, 1970 in filename in order make
    # a unique filename that the browser has not chached
    plotfile = os.path.join('static', str(time.time()) + '.png')
    plt.savefig(plotfile)
    return plotfile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print compute(1, 0.1, 1, 20)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import InputForm
from compute import compute
import os

def index(request):
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    result = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form2 = form.save(commit=False)
            result = compute(form2.A, form2.b, form2.w, form2.T)
            result = result.replace('static/', '')
    else:
        form = InputForm()

    return render_to_response('vib1.html',
            {'form': form,
             'result': result,
             }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

To be frank i am not too sure if this is the proper way to do it. From what i understand, views are rendered at the client computer. However, if it requires intensive resources, it should be done at the server end. Am i getting something wrong here?

Or how should this whole thing be?

Comment: incorrect, views aren't processed on the clients computer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I don't feel like downvote is the solution here. All of us have been beginners, and this is an honest mistake based on confusing naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

> views are rendered at the client computer.

This is just incorrect, views are *processed* on the server, and then the views *response* is what is sent back to the client.

In a normal html response, the clients browser then renders the html.

The only processing a clients machine ever has to do is whatever is done on the client side (angular, javascript, et al).

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong. views.py functions are not front end code, they are back end code. You mind is still attached to the concept `MVC`, but in django it's like `MVT`, where the `views` in django is the `controller` in `MVC` and django's html `template` corresponds the concept of `view` in `MVC`. All python code is executed on the server, only html and javascript that you have in the templates are rendered on the client side.